# How to calculate the longest length of a symmetrical string in a given string

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Write a function that returns the longest palindrome in a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115001/write-a-function-that-returns-the-longest-palindrome-in-a-given-string)

For example, the given string is "google", then the longest symmetrical string is "goog",therefore the answer should be 4. Any fast algorithm to solve it?

Comment: is "goxog" symmetrical string too?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043778/longest-palindrome-in-a-string-using-suffix-tree/11258994#11258994

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Longest (common) palindromic string search is similar to longest sub-sequence problem.

Try [this](http://www.leetcode.com/2011/11/longest-palindromic-substring-part-i.html) n [this](http://www.leetcode.com/2011/11/longest-palindromic-substring-part-ii.html) to learn about it in detail.