# Java: Most efficient way to check if a String is in a wordlist

Tags: java, string-comparison

I have an array of strings `String[] words` and a 28000 word Word-list.

I want to check if any member of the String array is in the WordList (the word-list is in a text file wordlist.txt)

What is the most efficient way to go about this?

Comment: Sounds like you are using the wrong data structure. A `HashSet` could be much better match.

Comment: this will take a lot of memory

Comment: Form a kd-tree with the word list, each alphabet is a dimension. Take your String[] word and find nearest neighbor in the tree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Place the strings directly into a `HashSet<String>` rather than an array and iterate through the file using [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) on the set to check the content. You wont improve on O(1) access. This will also mimimize memory used to store the `Strings` should any duplicates exist.

Comment: So its not a good idea to read the whole wordlist into a HashSet aswell then?

Comment: No, you'll want to remove duplicates to reduce memory footprint so using a HashSet directly is the way (plus you wont have to repopulate the HashSet - tiny added win in terms of code use also!)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the array (tree) suffix algorithm, but you need to implement, look this:

[Longest palindrome in a string using suffix tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043778/longest-palindrome-in-a-string-using-suffix-tree)

Answer (score 1):

Step1:Don't use string array. Instead of use HashSet.

Step2: Load the file(that is wordlist.txt) contents into another HashSet

Step3:

```
Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>(); //Load the string array into set
    Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>(); //load the file contents into set
    for (String str : set1) {
        for (String str2 : set2) {
            if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(str2)) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be faster to check if set2.contains(str).  That is an order 1 operation and one of the main benefits of using sets.  It turns this from O(n^2) to O(n)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HashSet<String>` or `ArrayList<String>` which has `contains` method. It will check if your String is stored or not.
The difference between `HashSet` and `ArrayList` is hashset won't allow duplicate value and it will not maintain the order while arraylist allows you duplicates and its an ordered collection.
But HashSet is more efficient than arraylist to perform a search operations.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend arraylist, that has to check all the items, whereas HashSet has to check .equals() for those that have the same hashCode()...

Comment: I would not call `ArrayList` search efficient for large lists.

Comment: I really think using Java's inbuilt data types for such a search is grossly inefficient.

Comment: @metsburg so you have a better implementation? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yea, HashSet is more efficient than ArrayList. I just showing him 2 ways and its difference

Comment: @PhilippSander A trie might qualify as more efficient, especially if the word list is large

Comment: @PhilippSander : Yes, a radix tree (or a Patricia trie) would be the best data structure for storing words. Hashset only makes sense in terms of memory usage, but radix tree is better since it avoids the time to compute hash keys. Also, predecessor/successor cannot be implemented using hash set. Moreover, Coherence API seems to provide a memory optimized radix tree implementation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22843/com/tangosol/util/BinaryRadixTree.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a `HashSet` of Strings as

```
HashSet<String> wordSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(words));
```

And Check for `word` in `HashSet` with [HashSet.contains(Object o)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method where `word` is the word you want to check if exists.

Answer (score 0):

Store instead of the original words.txt a serialized HashSet. As a separate step from running the application.

The application then only needs to load the hash set once.

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet`'s `add()` returns false if the word is already present in the set.

```
for (String str : words) {
  if (!wordSet.add(str)) {
    System.out.println("The word " + str + " is already contained.");
  }
}
```

This is a bit more sophisticated and less low-level than `contains()`.

Answer (score 0):

A HashSet will suffice if your list of words can fit in memory.

If memory size is a concern use a [BloomFilter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). While it is possible for bloom filter to give the wrong answer, you can tune the probability with which it happens.